# Is it acceptable not to include nationality and the date of birth into CV?

Tags: resume, united-states, europe

I have recently received some criticism that my CV does not include the date of birth and nationality, and I that should add this information in further applications.

From the other side, I am not sure if it is moral to use this information as a selection criteria during the hiring process, especially for pre-screening before the first interview (where any questions could be asked).

The age can probably be inferred from other dates like university graduation. I am not young but still no so old that it would have major impact on my productivity.

The nationality-based selection seems of questionable legality (there is a work-allowing residence permit that I mention in the CV).

However if for some reason this information is highly expected, I would of course include it. Is it a requirement?

**Edit:** This question mostly applies to USA and European Union as I am looking for a job in both.

Comment: At least here in Scandinavia, you should ALWAYS say if you're an EU citizen or not. Since not being one, you will likely not get chosen because of cost and visa implications - unless your field is in demand. So yes, include nationality. Age is very normal to include as well.

Comment: I'd leave nationality off for the US. Visa implications do matter, but nearly every application I remember filling out asks about your work status and whether you are legally required to get a visa to be able to work. So listing your nationality would be both redundant and too much info.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Would be interesting to see from whom the criticism came,  and where you are based.

My answer would be, as a hiring manager and candidate over 20 years plus,  going from Junior developer to senior program manager,  and someone who has never had either date of birth or nationality on my CV is:

**No it should not require having either on your CV**

You are more likely to be discriminated against if you mention age or nationality before they meet you and can be ruled out simply by including these details.

I will caveat that where I did mention my nationality in some covering letters,  but that was part of an international move and I wanted to draw attention that I had the nationality of the country where I was applying (so it was to my benefit).

Comment: The normal approach to saying you don't need immigration sponsorship is to say "Authorized to work for any employer in X country".

Comment: @DJClayworth - sure,  but I found I got a better response when I both mentioned my nationality AND that I was applying as part of existing plans to relocate to the country/area.  The general feedback I got was that was good as they would be interested but initially hesitant when they saw my location in case I wanted relocation expenses or were worried I may pull out late in the process.

Comment: I have rarely seen a German CV not mentioning age or birth date (google for "lebenslauf" and look at picture results). There is a big cultural difference between USA/UK and the rest of Europe regarding those items.

Comment: @Étienne I'm from germany, and failing to include these things is very likely to get your resume binned in the first pass. Some companies who allow online applications won't even let you submit without this data, for instance.

Comment: Yes but also the situation in Germany may improve with awareness growing it is unprofessional. Also, beware of [job scam](http://www.which.co.uk/consumer-rights/advice/job-scams-employment-fraud)

Answer (score 15):

This is highly dependent on your country and local culture. In the US age is a big no no, in Germany, age, marital status and number of children is pretty much the norm.

Nationality is a bit different. If your name doesn't sound or you don't look like a native, you should have a sentence about your legal status and work permissions. Your employer needs to know whether visa sponsorship or some such is required and you don't want to let them guess.

If you are worried about age discrimination you should rephrase the question as such or ask a new one. What you put or don't put on the resume is really of no consequence in this matter. People find out anyway.

Comment: In the US, an employer asking your age, marital status, existence of children is illegal.  Including this discrimination-ridden information on your resume makes you basically unemployable

Answer (score 4):

Im going to offer a different perspective, I am from germany.

It is completly normal here to include date of birth, place of birth and nationality in the CV. Not including it here will most likely get your resume binned right away. There is a sort of template for CVs here ("Lebenslauf"), and not following it or missing crucial information (like Age, date of birth, nationality, etc) will almost automatically disqualify you from most positions.

So while it might be acceptable not to include it in other countries, like the US or the UK, in Germany it is definitely not advisable.

Comment: It's not that it's acceptable to not include it in the US, it's that including it would get your cv binned.  Because it's illegal for the employer to ask those questions, and so answering them would make you an accomplice in that illegal activity.  Not worth detangling for them